# In Android; How can I call a method of a Foreground Service without Restarting the service?

Tags: android, service, notifications, action

I have a Foreground Service that shows remaining time, the notification also has some Action buttons to pause or stop the timer.For most of the similar question's answers are based on restarting the service with new intent. Is there any other way to call methods inside a service other than restarting the service.

Comment: If the service is running already and you send an intent to it, it does not restart.

Comment: @tyczj thanks for information , Since most of codes, check the actions inside  `onStartCommand()` , so i misunderstood that this would reset my variables , timer  etc.. and have to assign them every time . I have been wondering for hours, that's a great help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.